# I created a "Cash Register" function for Freecodecamp but for some reason the last two tests aren't passing?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, testing, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I created this function but the last two tests

```
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.01], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 1], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]) should return {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}.
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]) should return {status: "CLOSED", change: [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]}.
```

don't pass. What is wrong in my code?

The task is:

> Design a cash register drawer function `checkCashRegister()` that accepts purchase price as the first argument (`price`), payment as the second argument (`cash`), and cash-in-drawer (`cid`) as the third argument.
>
> `cid` is a 2D array listing available currency.
>
> The `checkCashRegister()` function should always return an object with a `status` key and a `change` key.
>
> Return `{status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}` if cash-in-drawer is less than the change due, or if you cannot return the exact change.
>
> Return {status: "CLOSED", change: [...]} with cash-in-drawer as the value for the key `change` if it is equal to the change due.
>
> Otherwise, return `{status: "OPEN", change: [...]}`, with the change due in coins and bills, sorted in highest to lowest order, as the value of the `change` key.

My code:

```js
const INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS = {
  status: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  change: []
};
const CLOSED_CID = {
  status: 'CLOSED',
  change: []
};
const POSITION_CID = [
  ['ONE HUNDRED', 100],
  ['TWENTY', 20],
  ['TEN', 10],
  ['FIVE', 5],
  ['ONE', 1],
  ['QUARTER', 0.25],
  ['DIME', 0.1],
  ['NICKEL', 0.05],
  ['PENNY', 0.01]
];
const add = (a, b) => a + b[1];
const checkCashRegister = (price, cash, cid) => {
  let finalChange = [];
  let changeDue = cash - price;
  const cidSum = cid.reduce(add, 0).toFixed(2);
  /*
  If there is exactly enough money to provide change, the
  status key is “CLOSED”, and the change key is our
  cash-in-drawer(cid).
  */
  if (cidSum == changeDue) {
    return {
      CLOSED_CID,
      change: cid
    };
  }
  /*
  If there is not enough money to provide change, the status key
  is “INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS” and the change key is an empty array.
  */
  if (cidSum < changeDue) {
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }
  /*
  If there is enough money to provide change with money still
  left in the drawer, the change is then provided by going down
  a list of currency units from high to low, pushing them to
  the change array, and subtracting them from both the cash
  owed and the cash-in-drawer(cid).
  */
  let cidReverse = cid.reverse();
  POSITION_CID.map((posCid, index) => {
    const billValue = posCid[1];
    while (changeDue >= billValue && cidReverse[index][1] >= billValue) {
      changeDue -= billValue; // minus change due from bill value
      changeDue = changeDue.toFixed(2); // fix rounding errors
      const hasBillValueAlready = finalChange.filter(p => p[0] === cidReverse[index][0]);
      if (hasBillValueAlready.length > 0) {
        finalChange = finalChange.map(k => (k[0] === posCid[0] && [k[0], (k[1] += billValue)]) || [k[0], k[1]]);
      } else {
        finalChange.push([cidReverse[index][0], billValue]);
      }
      cidReverse[index][1] -= billValue; // minus bill value from cash-in-drawer
    }
  });
  if (changeDue !== 0) {
    return {
      status: 'OPEN',
      change: finalChange
    };
  } else {
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }
};
const price = 19.5;
const cash = 200;
const cid = [
  ['PENNY', 1.01],
  ['NICKEL', 2.05],
  ['DIME', 3.1],
  ['QUARTER', 4.25],
  ['ONE', 90],
  ['FIVE', 55],
  ['TEN', 20],
  ['TWENTY', 60],
  ['ONE HUNDRED', 100]
];
// checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid);

console.log(
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]),
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.01], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 1], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]),"should return", `{status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}`,
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]), "should return", `{status: "CLOSED", change: [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]}`)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please format the result in a useful manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues to fix:

- When the change due is exactly what is in the cash register, the code returns an object that does not have the right structure:

  ```
  return {
    CLOSED_CID,
    change: cid
  };
  ```

  This will create a property `CLOSED_CID` which has as value an object with a nested `status` and `change` property... and you add yet another `change` property at the parent level. Instead, you should just forget about the predefined `CLOSED_CID` object, and do this:

  ```
  return {
    status: "CLOSED",
    change: cid
  };
  ```
- The decision whether to return the status `OPEN` or `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` should be on the opposite condition. It is when you have attributed *all* of the change amount to bills that you should return `OPEN`. So change this:

  ```
  if (changeDue !== 0) {
    return {
      status: 'OPEN',
      change: finalChange
    };
  } else {
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }
  ```

  to:

  ```
  if (changeDue == 0) { // All change could be translated to available bills/coins
    return {
      status: 'OPEN',
      change: finalChange
    };
  } else { // There is change remaining that cannot be covered by available bills/coins
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }
  ```

As a remark: the `toFixed` method returns a string. It would be better to explicitly convert the result back to number data type. There is currently no problem with it in your code, as that conversion happens implicitly when you do `-=` and `==`, but for code maintenance reasons you'd better not rely on that. So add a unary `+` whenever you call `toFixed`:

```
const cidSum = +cid.reduce(add, 0).toFixed(2);
// ...
changeDue = +changeDue.toFixed(2);
```

I would however suggest to do all calculations in cents, so all calculations are done with integer values, which do not suffer from the imprecision you otherwise need to cope with.

I assume you already found solutions [on the web](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/blob/master/curriculum/challenges/english/02-javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register.english.md), and there are [many Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.be/search?q=checkCashRegister+site:stackoverflow.com) about this same challenge.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I have tried to make things clear and easy to understand.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  const INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS = {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}
  const CLOSED = {status: "CLOSED", change: cid}
  const OPEN = {status: "OPEN", change: []}
  let totalCid = cidTotal();
  let dueBlance = parseFloat((cash - price).toFixed(2));

  if(totalCid < dueBlance) {
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }

  if(totalCid === dueBlance) {
    return CLOSED;
  }

  let cashTypes = [
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
  ];

  //console.log(caseTypes.length);

  for(let i = 0; i < cashTypes.length; i++) {
    let cashType = cashTypes[i][0];
    let cashValue = cashTypes[i][1];
    let totalCash = cid.find(item => item[0] === cashType)[1];

    if(dueBlance > cashValue && dueBlance > totalCash ) {
      dueBlance -= totalCash;
      OPEN.change.push([cashType, totalCash]);
    }else if(dueBlance > cashValue && totalCash > dueBlance) {
      let pay = Math.floor(dueBlance / cashValue) * cashValue;
      dueBlance -= pay;
      dueBlance = parseFloat(dueBlance.toFixed(2));
      OPEN.change.push([cashType, pay]);
    }
  }

  if(dueBlance > 0) {
    return INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS;
  }
  
  return OPEN;

  function cidTotal() {
    return parseFloat(cid.reduce((a,b) => a + b[1], 0).toFixed(2));
  }
}

let result = checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.01], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 1], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
    //all money values are multiplied by 100 to deal with precision errors 
    involved with decimals 
    const denomination = [10000, 2000, 1000, 500, 100, 25, 10, 5, 1,];

   function transaction(price, cash, cid) {
    let changeNeeded = (cash - price) * 100;
    //money will be pushed to the second value in each array
    let moneyProvided = [
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 0], 
    ["TWENTY", 0], 
    ["TEN", 0], 
    ["FIVE", 0], 
    ["ONE", 0], 
    ["QUARTER", 0], 
    ["DIME", 0], 
    ["NICKEL", 0], 
    ["PENNY", 0],
  ];
  //take the cid, reverse it (like in Roman Numerals exercise), multiply values by 100
  let availCash = [...cid].reverse().map(el => [el[0], el[1] * 100]);
  //get the total sum of all cash and divide by 100
  let sumOfCash = availCash.reduce((a, b) => (a + b[1]),0) / 100;
  //if sumOfCash is exact change needed return
  if (sumOfCash === changeNeeded / 100) {
    return {status: "CLOSED", change: [...cid]};
  }
  //else, run this function
  else for (let i = 0; i < availCash.length; i++) {
    //if denomination values are less than changeNeeded and availableCash values are greater than 0, run the while loop
      while (denomination[i] <= changeNeeded && availCash[i][1] > 0) {
        //1. moneyProvided array is increased by denomination value
        moneyProvided[i][1] += denomination[i];
        //2. changeNeeded is decreased by same denomination value
        changeNeeded -= denomination[i];
        //3. availCash is also decreased by same denomination value
        availCash[i][1] -= denomination[i];
      }
    };
    
   //clean up the moneyProvided array by
    let change = moneyProvided
    //1. resetting the money values by dividing by 100
    .map(el => [el[0], el[1] / 100])
    //2. filtering out all non-empty dollar and value arrays
    .filter(el => el[1] !== 0);
    //calculate the total of the change array
    let changeTotal = change.reduce((a, b) => (a + b[1]),0);
    //if the total change is less than the change needed
    if (changeTotal < changeNeeded) {
        return {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []};
    }
    return {status: "OPEN", change};
  }
  let answer = transaction(price, cash, cid);
  return answer;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).